# is there any Gradle inbuilt feature equivalent to Maven's “copy-dependencies” without writing gradle task..?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

looks like gradle still not mature when compared to maven.many handy features not available in gradle.

is there any Gradle inbuilt feature equivalent to Maven's “copy-dependencies” without writing gradle task..?

Answer (score 0):

Please check installDist task of [distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html).

You have to write code like this:

```
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = 'someName'
        contents {
            from { 'src/readme' }
            into { '../../' } // <----- change destination here
        }
    }
}
```

This plugin will create distribution installation, which will also copy all [runtime dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_types.html).

Comment: Here I don’t want to touch build.gradle file.... in maven, to copy dependencies just need to execute from cmd directly no need to add any script in POM.xml ... similarly any command available in gradle?

Comment: @KrishnaNagidi, I think it is not possible for now like in maven. Sorry, I did not understand initial question.

Comment: not a problem... thank you very much for your support.appreciate it.